# Stop “Sharing Suggestion” spam

Tags: ios, photos, photos.app, notifications

This morning my iPhone interrupted me with a random solicitation to use its Photos app:

> [image: Sharing Suggestion notification from the Photos app in iOS]

I am sick of applications abusing notifications to increase “user engagement”, and am saddened to see Apple finally succumbing to the trend.

How can I opt out of receiving these notifications?

Answer (score 6):

On iOS, this can be disabled in **Settings** -> Notifications -> Photos -> „option at bottom“ -> Sharing Suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The setting to opt out is located under headings called **Style** and **Appearance**:

Settings → Notifications → Notification Style: Photos → Lock Screen Appearance: Customize Notifications → Sharing Suggestions