# is there a way to turn off the obnoxious "sharing suggestions" on iOS?

Tags: ios

Often I take a photo, and go to my messages, select a conversation and choose the Photos app, and as I am about to tap on the photo I want to send, everything obnoxiously slides up and gives me this dialog "Sharing Suggestions - get sharing suggestions and easily send photos to anyone you choose using a link..."

And I ask my phone: "WHY are you constantly bugging me with this obnoxious nonsense?!?!"

Can I turn this off? I really am getting sick of this obtrusive nonsense interrupting me from what I am trying to do...

***UPDATE**  Someone closed this question saying it is a duplicate of [Stop “Sharing Suggestion” spam](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/455215/stop-sharing-suggestion-spam)

This is not the same issue...  Also, I have notifications for "Siri & Search" already turned off, as well as Settings > Notifications > Photos.

I found someone with my issue on discussions.apple.com:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251861293

And there is a reply there saying there is no way to turn it off other than to use iCloud, which I refuse to do.  Apple products should start coming with a free trial anger management session with a licensed therapist.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you're describing? When I tap photos it just shows me my photos.

Comment: @Ezekiel i updated my question with a link to someone having the same problem with a screenshot.

Comment: Please don’t just “the question is different.”  How specifically is it different?

Comment: Also, make sure the question stands on its own and doesn't expect people to follow an off-site link to hunt for details somewhere else.

Comment: I was able to turn off the photo sharing suggestions appearing occasionally by following the advice in the duplicate and without turning off iCloud in iOS 16. What's your iOS version and iPhone model? Can you pls share the screenshot for what you have within Settings -> Notifications -> Photos -> Customize Notifications (option at bottom).

Comment: @Alper I am on an iPhone 12 mini with iOS 14.  There is no Custom Notifications option for me.  The only thing on that settings page is "Allow Notifications" which I have off.

Comment: I suggest you update your post to include all this information and also include the screenshots of relevant parts of the settings for both Settings->Notifications-> Photos, and Settings->Siri & Search. On the other hand, I am surprised you do not have this setting because the duplicate is from Feb. '21 and the latest iOS version by then was iOS 13. Not sure why, but perhaps the lack of this setting might have something to do with your iPhone's model being 12 mini.

Comment: It seems pretty clear this can't be resolved without turning on iCloud Photos, unfortunately.